# Show that $\sum_{i=0}^{2n} (-1)^ix^i = \frac{x^{2n+1}+1}{x+1}$

Tags: summation

How can one show that if $x\neq-1$:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2n} (-1)^ix^i = \frac{x^{2n+1}+1}{x+1}$$

I know that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} r^{i-1} = \frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$

But then how to proceed?

Comment: You know of geometric series?

Comment: You must have heard of geometric series?

Comment: @YujieZha It's finite, so what do you mean by 'convergence'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2n} (-1)^ix^i =\sum_{i=0}^{2n} (-x)^i =  \frac{(-x)^{2n+1}-1}{-x-1} = \frac{(x)^{2n+1}+1}{x+1}$$